# clojure - return the average of all numbers in a tree

Tags: clojure

Problem 1.3 
(a)
 Write a function called nested-average, which takes a nested list of numbers as its only argument (i.e. a tree). Function nested-average should return the average of all numbers in the tree. For example  (nested-average ' (10 ((30 1) 20) (8 (5 (50 7)) 9) 40))   ==> 18 
(b) Similar to 2.4 but the new function (called "stats") returns the smallest, largest, count and average profile of numbers in a tree. Values to be returned in a map. 
(c) As above but takes a sequence of comparators (like <, >=, or user defined) to determine which stats are returned

Comment: Please add what you have tried and how it failed, so we can improve from there. SO is no offshore coding service.

Answer (score 4):

```
(defn bounds [tree]
  (apply (juxt min max) (flatten tree)))

(bounds '(1 (-2 17 (4)) -8 (-6 13)))
=> [-8 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to do this is

```
(defn bounds [l]
  [(first (sort (flatten l))) (last (sort (flatten l)))])
```

To save an invocation of `sort` you could use

```
(defn bound [l]
  (let [s (sort (flatten l))]
    [(first s) (last s)]))
```

And to satisfy the "mixed" requirement you could add an invocation of `filter`:

```
(defn bounds [l]
  (let [s (sort (filter number? (flatten l)))]
    [(first s) (last s)]))
```

Comment: thanks m8, my tutor said he only wants the min and max using head and tail recursion how would i do this ? thanks in advance

Comment: One way would be to bury a sort implementation in your function and recursively call it until the collection is sorted, then return the first and last elements of the sorted collection. To determine if a collection is sorted you can use `(defn is-ordered? [compare-func col] (not (contains? (set (map #(try (apply compare-func %) (catch Exception e true)) (partition 2 1 col))) false)))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a recursive solution.

```clj
(defn bounds [tree]
  (letfn [(find-min-max [tree mi ma]
            (reduce (fn [[mi ma] elm]
                      (cond
                        (number? elm) (if (and (nil? mi) (nil? ma))
                                        [elm elm]
                                        [(min mi elm) (max ma elm)])
                        (coll? elm) (find-min-max elm mi ma)
                        :default [mi ma]))
                    [mi ma]
                    tree))]
    (find-min-max tree nil nil)))
```

```clj
(bounds [1 [2 3 [4 [5 6 [7 [8 [9] -99 [11 [12 "ss" [34 [34 [34 [23 [23 :some-key]]]]]]]]]]]]]);; => [-99 34]
```

Comment: thanks your a legend, i am at college atm and needed this for my weekly studies, how would i also return the strings with the numbers ?

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to consider strings with numerical values ? Like "99", "10.0" ...  Then create a function that attempts to convert a numerical string to a number. If the function doesn't  succeed, it should just return nil. Add a let clause at the beginning of reducing function (let [elm (or (my-to-int-fn elm) elm)]..